# Upload PHP File to IP Address

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to upload some files to my device's IP Address, but I don't know how to do this.
So, I need to upload a .php file named: base.php to my IP Address on my wifi phone.
Then I have send a POST method to it to decode my image byte array back to an image.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new
HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:80/android/base.php");
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
is = entity.getContent();
```

So how would I upload my php file to my WiFi Ip Address? 
And secondly, Would it be possible to change this code:

```
HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:80/android/base.php");
```

to:

```
HttpPost("http://www.mywebsite.com/android/base.php");
```

And receive the image over there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi i think i understood your problem... what you need to do is to download an image file from a server to your device right??... if so try follow this link to [know how to download a file from an url](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-download-fileimage-url-your-device)

Hope this helps you...